# Can't save Matplotlib images to a readable .tif format

Tags: python, matplotlib, tiff

I'm having trouble saving my Matplotlib plots to a readable .tiff format. The file itself does save, but when I double-click on it on the folder, I get the following error in Windows Photo Viewer:

"Windows Photo Viewer can't open this picture because either Photo Viewer doesn't support this file format, or you don't have the latest updates to Photo Viewer."

But attempted workarounds such as trying to load the file with Paint or Photo do not work. I get the feeling that the file is not saving correctly. (The image displays just fine and can be saved as a .gif just fine.) How do I resolve this?

Comment: Can you upload the image or give a [mcve] that generates said image? There are issues known with photo viewer opening large tiffs, which you can easily find more about on the internet. If you're unsure, just post the code or the image.

Comment: also, can you try it/have someone else try it on a different OS with a different viewer?